# execute program as computer account

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos

Given a joined Windows 8 or 10 system, how does one run some script with the
credentials of the *computer* account? *Without installing any third
party tools*, just a vanilla Windows install.

The purpose is to verify access of automated processes (think Windows Update
for a practical example) to certain domains in a test scenario.

Alternatively it would probably suffice to just obtain a TGT for the computer
principal (`SOMEBOX$@MYREALM.ORG`) and use that from a regular account, but
for that I’d need to extract the computer password to perform preauthentication.
Not sure how to accomplish that either.

Comment: Pretty unclear what you're trying to do and what's the actual situation.

Comment: @harrymc: “Pretty unclear what you're trying to do and what's the actual
situation.” — Assume there’s a binary located at ``C:\tmp\myprogram.exe``,
execute this with the appropriate parameters in a context where Kerberos
initial credentials of the computer / machine account are present in the
credentials cache.

Comment: You left out a lot of stuff, so let me try: What does it mean "a joined Windows 8 or 10 system"? What does the credentials cache have to do with running an executable on the local computer? How do the wanted credentials differ from the current user? Are you trying to emulate another user *and computer* and what for? Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1623434/edit) your post rather than commenting.

Comment: @harrymc: “What does it mean "a joined Windows 8 or 10 system"?” – joined according to
[[MS-ADTS], section 6.4](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/d2435927-0999-4c62-8c6d-13ba31a52e1a).
Also note the question is tagged *active-directory* for a reason.
“What does the credentials cache have to do with running an executable on the
local computer?” – You have it backwards. The binary should be able to access
the credentails cache while host creds are present.

Comment: “How do the wanted credentials differ from the current user?” – As described in
the AD specs. “Are you trying to emulate another user and computer and what
for?” – No. “Please edit your post rather than commenting.” – Why? These
comments have little to do with my question.